# org.luaj : luaj-jse library performance in kotlin

Tags: performance, kotlin, luaj

I am using the this library,org.luaj:luaj-jse:3.0.1, to compile lua script in kotlin . This script has functions defined in lua and others defined in kotlin class which i load to the globals. The purpose of this is to carry out some functions on database related entries. I append a certain formula call to the script and call it to return the value. This is done by feeding the luaService the a list of formulas one after the other. I find that this endpoint takes a lot of time and I think the library used is the issue . Do you have insight on a different library that i could use to compile lua in kotlin?

I need to find a way to increase the service's performance thus enhancing the endpoint's. I can not find a solution.